# why is .attr() method not working in jQuery 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used this property in 1.8.3 but this doesnt seem to work now

```
 if ($("#checkbox").attr("checked")) 
    {
    alert("Checked");
    }
    else
        {
        alert("Not checked");
        }
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/7VQbN/) where the above code works for 1.8.3

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/7VQbN/1/) where the same code is not working for 1.9

Comment: Read the DOC: "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method."

Comment: Got more number of downvotes but still thats fine.
I just want to get clarified
Hope downvotes are not just because the question is simple!!
Plus I dont think its a duplicate of any question as the issue I am facing is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checked` is not an attribute of checkbox.It is a property.Before `jquery 1.6` attr was used to change the checked property of checkbox which was wrong so removed in newer version.So `prop` was added as new feature to change the property of control.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using `.attr` to see if a checkbox is checked -- 1.9 [introduced a breaking change](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-).  Use `.prop` instead.

Comment: oh is it deprecated in 1.9!? because the same is working in 1.8.3

Comment: @vignesh: It was removed really. The link explains.

Comment: It's not deprecated... The way in which you're using it *is*. `.attr()` is still the preferred method when dealing with non-input element attributes, and I guess attributes that don't get changed natively by user interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")){
    alert("Checked");
}
else{
    alert("Not checked");
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VQbN/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.6, the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)  method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VQbN/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prop` instead of `.attr`

Also, you are using `.live` in your fiddle, which is not supported in the jquery version you are using,
you need to use `.on()` instead of `.live`

Demo `---->`  http://jsfiddle.net/7VQbN/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if ($("#checkbox").prop("checked")){
    alert("Checked");
}
else{
    alert("Not checked");
}
```

As mentioned in [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc) API docs:-

> **Before jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values
>   into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause
>   inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a
>   way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves
>   attributes.

Comment: thanks palash 
so now in 1.9+ the .attr() is used only for setting some attribute

Comment: yeah, for both setting & retrieving attributes..